# java:S1121: "Extract the assignment out of this expression."

Tags: java, if-statement, sonarqube

I've a big java project given by my teacher for the exam, and analysis with SonarCloud gives me this Code Smell to fix on this function

```
private long selIsBidAction(boolean isBidAction, long takerReserveBidPrice, DirectOrder makerOrder) {
    if(isBidAction) {
        return takerReserveBidPrice;
    } else {
        return makerOrder.reserveBidPrice;
    }
}
```

In particular it's about `if(isBidAction)`. I thought to put `isBidAction=true` immediately upon that if to fix this. Could it be a solution?

Comment: That's the same thing... I suggest you to use short-return... I don't see any errors...

Comment: `return isBidAction ? takerReserveBidPrice : reserveBidPrice`?

Comment: Did SonarQube give you any error message more specific than this?  I don't see any code smell actually.

Comment: Seems like you used `if(isBidAction = true)` instead of `if(isBidAction == true)`. In any case, `if(isBidAction)` is what you want to use, if you should stick to the if statement at all (you can change this to a conditional expression)

Comment: @Tim Biegelisen SonarQube says that the code smell is about the line where there is if(isBidAction)

Comment: When you look at the [Sonar Qube Rule Repository RSPEC-1121](https://jira.sonarsource.com/browse/RSPEC-1121) you find that the non-compliant code contains an assignment. So your code should be OK - maybe the complaint is about an older version that was `if(isBidAction = true) {...}`

Comment: @AndreaMa To add to the comment given by **ernest_k** above, I consider your version to be the correct code style.  Please consider disabling this particular rule.  Using `==` with boolean primitives actually feels like the bigger smell to me.

Answer (score 2):

SonarQube tells you that methods whose the whole logic executions depend on an input `boolean` parameter is a bad practice. Your structure is equivalent to:

```java
Object method(boolean condition, Object logic1, Object logic2) {
    if (condition) {
        return logic1;
    } else {
        return logic2;
    }
}
```

The usage is as follows:

```java
Object result = method(condition, logic1, logic2)
```

This method doesn't bring any value. It only hides the `if-else` statement which could may decrease the code readability. You should inline it:

```java
Object result = condition ? logic1 : logic2;
```

In your case:

```java
long price = isBidAction ? takerReserveBidPrice : makerOrder.reserveBidPrice;
```

When the logic is more complex, you may create a method to extract required value, but still don't hide the `if-else` condition:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
   // ...
   long price = isBidAction ? takerReserveBidPrice : getOrderPrice(makerOrder)
   // ...
}

private long getOrderPrice(Order order) {
    // some complex logic here
}
```

Of course there is no sense to create a such method only to execute the `makerOrder.reserveBidPrice` condition (it is too simple).

Btw. SonarQube marks only these methods which full logic executions depend on a simple condition. It means that this

```java
void method(boolean condition) {
    if (condition) {
        // logic
    } else {
        // logic
    }
}
```

would be marked as issue, but this code not:

```
void method(boolean condition) {
    // logic
    if (condition) {
        // logic
    } else {
        // logic
    }
    // logic
}
```